# no decode delegate for this image format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/575

Tags: command, imagemagick, ghostscript, imagick

> PHP ImageMagick giving error for a corrupted pdf file. Pdf opening
> with reader but ImageMagick saying "no decode delegate for this image
> format `' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/575". With convert command It
> is saying "**** Warning: File has some garbage before %PDF- ." but it
> converting too.

how can I solve this?
Please help me.

.....

```
try {
$document = new \Imagick($path);
} catch(\Exception $e) {
$this->logger->critical(sprintf('[ImageService] Cant load file %s into imagick. ', $path) . $e->getMessage());
return;
}
```

......

Comment: Be sure you have a current version of Ghostscript and that your policy.xml file permits PDF/PS/EPS.  Be sure that the PDF is not corrupt, also.

Comment: Convert is calling Ghostscript to render the PDF file, and the warning from Ghostscript is that there is 'garbage before %PDF'. So I'd guess that IM simply can't determine what the file type is, because it doesn't see the %PDF in whatever chunk of the file it is looking at. I suspect your only solution is to remove the garbage, which may corrupt the file irretrievably, depending on whether the cross-reference table is built expecting it to be present or not. Basically your file is broken, you need to fix it.